# How do I retrieve a password from Keychain Access using keyring?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, keychain, python-keyring

"Keeping credentials safe in Jupyter Notebooks" (https://towardsdatascience.com/keeping-credentials-safe-in-jupyter-notebooks-fbd215a8e311) says that "Keyring integrates with your OS keychain manager... You would use it as"

```
import keyring
keyring.get_keyring()
keyring.get_password("system", "username")
```

On Mac Ventura 13.2.1, I open Keychain Access, click "Create a new Keychain item.", enter Keychain Item Name "PostgreSQL_Password", account name "tslever", and password "my_password". I restart Anaconda Navigator, JupyterLab, and a Jupyter Notebook. I enter

```
import keyring
keyring.get_keyring()
print(keyring.get_password("PostgreSQL_Password", "tslever"))
```

`None` is printed.

Comment: The `get_keyring()` call does nothing.  That just returns the current default keyring.  If you do `set_password`, do you get the correct information back to you?  Try doing `set_password` and see what changes in the Keychain app.

Comment: `import keyring; keyring.set_password('system', 'tslever', 'my_password'); keyring.get_password('system', 'tslever')` returns `my_password`. I am missing any change to Keychain Access. Where is this password set?

Comment: Now, just to make sure, are you running this on a LOCAL Jupyter notebook, and not on some other server?

Comment: I am running JupyterLab on a MacBook Pro 2021 with Apple M1 MAX CPU.

Comment: The code is setting this in the kSecClassGenericPassword class.  Have you gone through the whole Keychain?